# how to automate the process to install the managed packages in scratch orgs

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, scratch-org

I Would like to automate the process to install the managed packages in scratch orgs so that I dont need to install the packages every time I create the scratch org for development. Any script or process that can provide solution to my problem, please let me know. Thanks!